# Why is firefox connecting to google servers?

Tags: firefox

I'm using [Firefox 39.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/39.0/releasenotes/) under [Debian Testing](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting). When I start Firefox, I can see several connections to servers like `wm-in-f102.1e100.net` in http and in https.

[1e100.net](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/174717?hl=en) is a Google-owned domain name used to identify servers in their network.

I've checked the Mozilla support page [How to stop Firefox from making automatic connections?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-stop-firefox-making-automatic-connections?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Firefox+makes+unrequested+connections)

My homepage is blank.

I've disabled all plugins and extensions, disabled all prefetching options, removed all search engines.

I've only left the Debian packages search engine becaus it's mandatory to have at least one search engine.

But firefox is still connecting to `1e100.net` servers.

How to explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox is [using Google's malicious site list](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-does-phishing-and-malware-protection-work) to check whether visited pages are safe. That would explain these connections being active.

Comment: You're right. Disabling `Block reported attack sites` and `Block reported web forgeries` in preferences, stop the connections.

Comment: Awsome, use your competitors data!